# Vk bot пишет другому боту

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, php-vksdk

У меня есть гениальный бот который по словарю отвечает на сообщения людей (словарь тысяч на 7 фраз + уникальные варианты для каждой фразы - больше нескольких миллионов ответов))

И я хочу сделать, чтобы он общался сам с собой. То есть например у меня есть группа с этим ботом - бот Григорий, и я хочу, чтобы он писал в группу с ботом Юрой, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я создал вторую группу с таким же ботом. В обоих группах разрешил добавлять бота в беседы. Создал беседу э и добавил туда обоих ботов. В messages.send() вместо user_id я использовал peer_id - тк в качестве его значения можно использовать user_id и chat_id. И этот peer_id я беру из объекта, которой отправляет мне ВК вместе с сообщением. В итоге бот может отвечать в диалоге с пользователем и в беседе.

Так у меня получилось сделать, что 2 бота отвечают на сообщения друг друга

Answer (score 0):

в чем заключается проблема? пишете асинхронный код с двумя функциями: longpool для первого, и для второго бота, который будет читать сообщения только от второго и первого соответсвенно.

для более просто версии: создайте два кода и в каждом делайте вышеуказанные действия. чтобы один бот, так сказать, не был стесняшкой и написал первым, перед лонгпулом отправьте второму сообщение методом  messages.send предварительно запустив его, чтобы он сразу ответил на пришедшее сообщение и начался «диалог».

Comment: Ну а как отправить сообщение от первого бота второму?

Comment: авторизуетесь, и методом messages.send, в аргументы указываете user_id второго